# Delete last 2/3 char of a string on button click (Java/android)

Tags: java, android, if-statement, onclick, onclicklistener

i tried to do a "simple" calculator on android.
when i click "Del" button i want that last number is deleted.
But when i want to delete "sin", "cos", "tan" or "ln" from the EditText(calulator display) i tried to find a way to delete the last 2/3 char instead of the last one.

this is the method that control on "Del" button click:

```
public void setDelOnClick(View v) {
    EditText viewCal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.viewCal);
    int lengthView = viewCal.getText().length();
    String viewCalString = viewCal.getText().toString();
    if(lengthView == 1)
        viewCal.getText().delete(0, 1);
    else if(lengthView > 1) {
        String last2Char = viewCalString.substring(lengthView -2, lengthView);
        switch(last2Char) {
            case "in":
                viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 3, lengthView);
                break;
            case "os":
                viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 3, lengthView);
                break;
            case "ln":
                viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 2, lengthView);
                break;
            default:
                viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 1, lengthView);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

but it work only if I don't delete the last char in the EditText. when i try to delete the last char, CRASH.
Can you help me to find a way to delete correctly what is in the calculator display?

my  tracktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
```

continue..

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; regionStart=-1; regionLength=2
        at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
        at com.gabrielemarcozzi.mycal.MainActivity.setDelOnClick(MainActivity.java:474)
```

if my code is:

```
public void setDelOnClick(View v) {
    EditText viewCal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.viewCal);
    int lengthView = viewCal.getText().length();
    if(lengthView > 0)
        viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 1, lengthView);
}
```

i can delete also the last char but in I want to delete "sin", it became "si" etc

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace of the exception you're getting?

Comment: What `Text` do you have right now on `lengthView`?

Comment: @Mick java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; regionStart=-1; regionLength=2

Comment: What do you mean with `it work if I don't delete the last char in the EditText`? Can you put an example? And, It shows to you the line in which the error comes?

Comment: @Error404 this problem is only when i try to delete the last char in the editText, I have  "8" as the last char in EditText.

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Correct me if I'm wrong please but do you mean when you have, for example, `sin8` and delete the `8` it gives to you the error?

Comment: if i write "8+3" and click "del" it works and became "8+" but if i delete the last char it crash

Comment: no, if i have "sin8" it work, and I can also delete "sin" after "8" because it is compose by 3 char

Comment: if i have "8sin" i can delete sin with one click but if I delete also 8 it crash

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Try to put `viewCal.getText().delete(1, 1);`

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi When the length it's equal to 1

Comment: @Error404 same error... :(

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Try to change `viewCal.getText().delete(0, 1);` to `viewCal.setText("");`

Comment: @Error404 doesn't work...

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi What it gives now to you?

Comment: @Error404 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity.....
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; regionStart=-1; regionLength=2

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi It references to some line or something?

Comment: @Error404 no, it don't reference to lines

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Can you try to debug your code and see where it crash?

Comment: @Error404 I don't know how to debug my code in Android studio.. sorry

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Look at this link. It will be very useful to know how to debug your code: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: @Error404 what do i do when i run in debug mode my app?

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi At the left bottom of your `Android Studio` you will have all your variables that you have on your programm (remember to put breakpoints into the code, I recommend you to put one in each line that you consider important and that could have the error). When the program stops (when he find a breakpoint) you have to see your variables and if their values are as expected. It's low, but very useful to debug your programs to catch programming erros.

Comment: @Error404 i've seen that when the editText length is equals to 1, the code doesn't enter in the if condition and crash ( if (lengthView == 1) )

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi can you store `viewCal.getText().delete(0, 1);` in a variable and say to me what value it has please?

Comment: @Error404 what type of variable?

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Look at if there is some option like `.toString()` or something like that. I think it would be a nice option to store it in a `String`.

Comment: @Error404 i've written this code in delButtonOnClick:
String delLast = viewCal.getText().delete(0, 1).toString();
Log.d("IO", delLast);

if in EditText i have "sin", the logcat shows "in" and the app crash.
if i have "58645", the logcat shows me "8645" and the app crash.

but if in editText there's only one char, the logcat shows me nothing and the app crash.

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi So now it always crash?

Comment: @Error404 in this case yes... if i comment    viewCal.getText().delete(0, 1).toString(); Log.d("IO", delLast);     it crash only if I want to delete the last char.

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Ok, it seems that `.delete(0,1)` as I supposed it's not working as expected. I'm 99% secure that the problem it's with 0,1.

Comment: @Error404 and how i can resolve my problem? it crash also with "viewCal.setText("");"

Comment: @Error404 and why if I have only one char, the code doesn't "enter" in if condition but it stops?

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi It's what I'm trying to focus. But I can't see what I am missing. I already had seen your code like 100 times.

Comment: @Error404 if my on Del click method is "public void setDelOnClick(View v) {
        EditText viewCal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.viewCal);
        int lengthView = viewCal.getText().length();
        if (lengthView > 0)
            viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 1, lengthView);
  }
i can delete also the last char, but if i want delete "sin", it became "si", so don't delete the last 3 char.

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Please add this last code to the question to be more clear.

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi I'm going to put an answer. I expect now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
public void setDelOnClick(View v) {
    EditText viewCal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.viewCal);
    int lengthView = viewCal.getText().length();
    String viewCalString = viewCal.getText().toString();
    if(lengthView > 0 && lengthView <=1)
        viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 1, lengthView);
    else
    { 
       if(lengthView > 1)
       {
          String last2Char = viewCalString.substring(lengthView -2, lengthView);

          switch(last2Char) {
           case "in":
            viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 3, lengthView);
            break;

           case "os":
            viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 3, lengthView);
            break;

           case "ln":
            viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 2, lengthView);
            break;

           default:
            viewCal.getText().delete(lengthView - 1, lengthView);
            break;
       }  }
    }
}
```

I expect now will works!

Comment: value of "viewCalString"?

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Sorry I though it was on the code.

Comment: it works only if "sin", "cos" or "ln" are the last char.
if i have "8 + sin" and i click Del, it became "8 + si".

Comment: Do you mean with the "+" inside the String?

Comment: plus operator..  also if i have "8sin", it became "8si"

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Ok it is because `switch` function searches the 100% comparison, so it is executing `default` mode. At least, now we know that it works. If you can wait some minutes I will edit my answer with another possibility.

Comment: there's another problem: if I click Del button when lengthView == 0, the app crash. this beacuse in the else condition should be also a lengthView > 0 condition

Comment: @Error404 deserves some award for how much time (s)he has spent on this question.

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Ok I added your substring. Now I think it has sense.

Comment: @Error404 it works perfectly!!  thank you very much!! also for how much time you have spent!! (and sorry for my english... i'm italian)

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Dont worry, I'm also not from England and my English its a bit weird :S. And please, mark it as accepted answer if it has the clue to your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`getText().clear()` is a convenience function for clearing out the field. It is short for `replace(0, length(), "", 0, 0)`

Try instead

```
if(lengthView == 1)
    viewCal.getText().clear();
```

Comment: Can you comment out         `viewCal.getText().delete(0, 1);` to see if it still crashes? I don't think that line is running.

Comment: If i comment that, I must delete "else if" and write "if", and if I click del button in the app, it delete nothing.. but the app doesn't crash!!